# How do I get an InfoPath 2010 form deployed with a WSP to work in a sub-site collection?

Tags: infopath, forms-services, solution-deployment

What I currently have is a SharePoint 2010 project that I have successfully deploying an InfoPath Browser Form (Full Trust) content type and associating it with library instances.

This is working just fine when deploying into the root site (e.g. `http://spdev`) but when I try to activate the features in a site collection below the root (e.g. `http://spdev/sites/list`) it fails to open the form via form services and instead tries to open via InfoPath.

Is this some sort of weird limitation to Form Services or am I missing some random attribute that will make this work?

Answer (score 2):

While deploying your feature you need to change the scope of your feature(feature.xml) as web. So when you activate the feature it will be activated for that subsite only.

Scope="web"

more can be found here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2007/05/03/sharepoint-features-elements-scope-and-other-info.aspx